# Ubuntu not recognizing all swap space

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, gparted, swap

I have issue regarding my swap size.

When I issue `htop` I get this output showing that I only have 2 GB of swap space:

[image]

Also when I check system monitor:

[image]

But, If I check the swap partition using `Gparted`, it is showing that I have 21 GB of swap space:

[image]

Also the output of `swapon -s` is:

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile                               file        2097148 0   -2
```

Why Ubuntu isn't using all available swap space and just using 2GB?

Comment: Type `free` in Terminal

Comment: My experience is that my computer only uses swap space when I am  low on RAM or hibernating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't properly set up your /etc/fstab.

There are two kinds of swap available to you. A /swapfile, or a partition-based swap area. You have to decide on one or the other.

**Note**: A 22G swap partition is excessive (unless you're planning on hibernating).

Your /etc/fstab currently has something like:

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

You should either increase your 2G /swapfile to 4G, or switch your swap line to use your /dev/sda7 swap partition, with something like:

```
UUID=071f8b0e-8e16-4f4d-90ff-a4ae9cc56e2b  none  swap       sw       0       0
```

**Note**: changing the UUID to what's found in the `sudo blkid` command.

---

To increase your current /swapfile to 4G, do the following:

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 16G RAM and 4G swap
```

Confirm this /swapfile line at the end of /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines...

To edit, use `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**Note**: Then you can remove your 22G swap partition /dev/sda7.

Answer (score 1):

`swapon -s` indicates the swap space that is currently in use. The output of your command indicates that a swapfile, `/swapfile`, is in use. Your swap partition is not used. For it to be used, it would need to be included into `/etc/fstab`. Currently, you will see an entry for `/swapfile`. You would need to add another entry for the swap partition.